# How to choose the title for a tales book?

Tags: publishing, book, titles

I'm publishing a tales book and I don't have a title for it. It's not for children and it's in spanish.

**update:**

These are the titles of the tales:

```
El hijo del escritor
Celular
El pelo en el jabón
El último en la cola
Instante cero
La máquina de los cuentos
La entrevista
La Oficina Media
Schwarzweiss
Personajes
Dulce Poppy
```

Comment: "Not for children Spanish tales book" - honestly, what do you expect? That we know your tales better than you do?

Comment: I find it strange that you got so far and are struggling over finding a title. Why not pick the title of one of the most representative of better tales and call it something like "X and other tales".

Comment: Voting to close as "Not a Real Question".

Comment: Raskolnikov: I was trying not to fall in the "and other tales" form.

Comment: John Smithers: title is no about the inner tales, it's about selling :)

Comment: @Juanjo: If you sell a Porsche catalog instead of your inner tales, you are doing it wrong. I'm interested in Porsches, but maybe not in your inner tales.

Comment: I'd pick "La máquina de los cuentos" (the story machine, if I translate correctly).  It could work as a book title, too, and sounds interesting to me.

Comment: Yeah, Adam's advice sounds good.

Comment: Since this is an English Q&A site, the tale titles should be translated (by someone) into English.  The Spanish versions can be here, but the question needs to be in English.

Comment: @Raskolnikov: not so strange - this is a publisher's question, not an author's.  And the OP didn't say they were the author. :)

Comment: OK, my bad, I should have read it better.

Answer (score 5):

If you're not the publisher, I wouldn't sweat it. The publisher will come up with a title; they always do.

Comment: s/title/bad title/  (sorry for being exceedingly technical ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Pick the story that represents the whole collection best and call it [That Story] & other tales, as someone already suggested.

Or pick a completely different name - try to figure out what it is that connects your stories, is it a theme, character? Is it anything at all? Do these tales work together, or is the only thing connecting them that they were written by you?

Comment: I think that'd usually be the longest tale, especially if one of them were significantly longer than any of the others

Answer (score 1):

The title of one of your stories "La máquina de los cuentos" (The story machine) is a title that could well cover such a series. I say this without knowing the theme of the different stories. I hope it serves you something.

Answer (score 0):

It really should be up to you. But how about: 'Juanjo Conti: a collection', translated obviously. I'm assuming you're the author.